# eclipse(sts) html editor highlight syntax

Tags: html, eclipse, syntax, syntax-highlighting, spring-tool-suite

I am struggle with html edit in STS IDE. I cant make work:

- syntax highlight
- code coloring

Here is print screen:
[image]

can any one help me?

Comment: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme

Answer (score 0):

I've soled it on my won.
It helped:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme

and this also:

http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin